# why i can't add library?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, namespaces, build.gradle, manifest

first i aded this code for add library in my build.gradle.kts:

`repositories{ google() mavenCentral() }`

and Android studio sayed this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZedJS.jpg

i can't add library.. help me guys

Comment: Show your code!  Can't help, if don't know what your are doing. Also show the error messages.